# Given $a, b, c, d, m \in\mathbb{Z}$such that $5\mid (am^3 + bm^2 + cm + d)$, prove that there exists integer $n$ such that...

Tags: modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Given $a, b, c, d, m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that  $5|(am^3 + bm^2 + cm + d)$ and $5 \not| d$ , prove that there exists an integer $n$ such that $5\mid(dn^3 + cn^2 + bn + a)$

I've spent about two hours trying to solve this problem but haven't been able to do so. Here's the furthest I've gotten:

$5\nmid d$ so $5\nmid m$ as well.

Case I: $5\mid a$ ... set $n = 0$

Case II: $5\nmid a$

$(am^3 + bm^2 + cm + d) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$

Then multiply the equation by $(m^3)^{-1}$ to make the $a$ coefficient 1, like so:

$(d (m^3)^{-1} +  c m (m^3)^{-1} + b m^2 (m^3)^{-1} + a) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$

Now the question remains... does there exist an integer $n$ such that:

$n \equiv m^2 (m^3)^{-1}$

$n^2 \equiv m (m^3)^{-1}$

$n^3 \equiv (m^3)^{-1}$

Comment: Pick an $n$ such that $mn\equiv 1 \pmod 5$. This is possible because $5 \not| d$.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically done. Choose $n=m^{-1}$ in $Z_5$. The existence of the multiplicative inverse of $m$ is guaranteed since $5$ is prime, which implies $Z_5$ is a field.